# PHP multiple checkboxes in Woocommerce product page

Tags: php, checkbox, woocommerce

I'm trying to make multiple checkboxes in the Woocommerce product page.
Managed to make one with 1 checkbox. I need 4 checkboxes though...
I'd appreciate it very much if you could point me in the right direction!

```
woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 
'id'            => '_checkbox', 
'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_simple', 
'label'         => __('My Checkbox Field', 'woocommerce' ), 
'description'   => __( 'Check me!', 'woocommerce' ) 
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "I need 4 checkboxes"? Can't you just call that function 4 times?

Comment: No i mean: label Which fruit?: 0 Apple 0 Orange 0 Banana 0 Lemon

Comment: You mean a set of multi checkboxes? Why not just write it in HTML? See [here](http://www.wastedpotential.com/html-multi-checkbox-set-the-correct-way-to-group-checkboxes/)